# Is a three-way associative relationship correct in this case

Tags: database-design, identity

So I have started modelling some entity relationships.

It goes as follows:

- A `Mandate` represent a client. A row for a client (Mandate) will only appear once in the `Mandate` table.
- Each `Mandate` can have one or more `Asset`, and the same `Asset` can be had by different `Mandates`. This is relationship is modelled through the `Mandate Asset Bridge`, in which a `Mandate ID` will be linked to one or more `Asset ID`.
- The goal of the `Asset` table is for an asset to be on a single row of the table (thus no two same assets will appear).
- The issue comes when considering `Security`. The security are parameters for `Asset` and are dependent on the `Mandate`, so `Mandate1` could have `Asset1` with `Security1`, and `Mandate2` could have `Asset1` with `Security2`. **There cannot exist an entry for `Security` without it being linked to an `Asset`.**
- At the moment, given the model, the same `Asset` will need to be duplicated for all different `Security` parameters. So while in `Asset`, the Bloomberg ID, Name, Underlying, etc... will always be the same, in the example above `Asset1` will need to be appear twice, once with the `Security1 FK` and once with the `Security2 FK`.
- This to me breaks some normalisation i.e., if the Bloomberg ticker changes, I have to go through the `Asset` table, and change that all occurrences of the same `Asset`

[image: Entity Relationship]

**Solution**

One possible way of solving this I guess is to create a three-way bridge table, which in my case would contain MandateID, AssetID, and Security ID.

I've never encountered a situation like this. Is this a good way of doing it? Intuitively I would say no, it does not seem very elegant, but I'm not sure.

See below for what a three-way associative relation would look like.

[image]

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Well second diagram *looks* better than first, (no weird `FKs`), however the rule *"There cannot exist an entry for Security without it being linked to an Asset."* does not hold. Problem is in wording, it is hard to understand. For example *Asset* has a ticker, say Apple Inc `AAPL`. *Security* has `ISIN`, say Apple `US0378331005`; but there is an association table in between? Describe relationship between asset and security. If *mandate* is a client (person, organization?) how do asset and security depend on it?

Comment: The relationships between them is as follows: A client (or mandate) can choose to invest in one or more assets. The asset represent the underlying asset the client wants to invest it (so like S&P 500). The asset gets it associated with the security once the bank chooses where the assets gets traded. Thus the security denotes the venue where the asset gets traded, which is defined by its ISIN, and which trades in a specific currency, and has a given delay post trade for any buy/sell transaction.

Comment: How many securities per an asset? Can a specific asset be associated with more than one security?

Comment: Yes exactly, one asset (so say the S&P 500) can be traded either in Luxembourg, in France, in Spain, etc... (and each of these will have a specific ISIN). So S&P 500 traded in Luxembourg will have been traded in that exchange with the ISIN LU123 and the S&P 500 traded in France will have isin FR456.